# Creating a flow that would fail for large files

Tags: sharepoint-online

The flow details are presented in the picture. The purpose is that whenever a new file is uploaded to folder1, it is moved to folder2. This works for small uploaded files up to maybe a couple of 100MB's. Note that this flow MOVES the files, and apparently the trigger runs before an upload is completed. The flow succeeds, but the original upload file disappears and gives an error, and the destination also does not include the file.

```
Error=Value=FileNotFound,Tag=xxx,Message=Exception=Microsoft.SharePoint.SPExceptionMessage=An unexpected error has occured, ...
```

[image: flow details]

Answer (score 0):

There is a message size limit for flow about 100Mb. This may be the reason why these large files missing.
[image]

You could use "Move to" feature as a workaround to move these large files.

For Reference: [Limits for automated, scheduled, and instant flows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/limits-and-config#message-size)